# How to plot a complex functions in complex plane?

Tags: plotting, complex

How to plot a complex equation like `f(z)=z^2`
in complex plane?
Is it required to separate the real and imaginary parts or it can be done directly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/228053/4999

Comment: @Michael E2: in mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/228053/4999 the plot of `Abs[z]<=4` is asked.

Comment: @user64494 A distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are `ComplexPlot` and `ComplexPlot3D` commands since version 12 of Mathematica. See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot3D.html for more info.

Comment: but kindly i would like to make in in 2d as contour plot

Comment: @view `ContourPlot[Re[(x + y I)^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` if you want the contours for the real part, `ContourPlot[Im[(x + y I)^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` if you want contours for the imaginary part, and `ContourPlot[Abs[(x + y I)^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` if you want contours for the norm of z^2.

Comment: @view: If you look in the documentation to `ComplexPlot`, you will see an example `ComplexPlot[((z^2 + I) (z^2 + 2 + 2 I))/(z + 2 + I)^2, {z, -3 - 3 I, 
  3 + 3 I}, Mesh -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &}]` to this end.

Comment: @view: An example `ComplexPlot[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, Mesh -> 20, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Log[Abs[#2]] &, Arg[#2] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {White, Black}]` may be useful too.

Comment: Although `ComplexPlot` and `ComplexPlot3D` help, they are not the whole story. Suppose one wants to show how the function maps a particular geometric shape, from a `z`-plane domain to a `w-plane` codomain? or how it maps a rectangular grid or circular grid?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Re(z^2)=x^2-y^2$ and $\Im(z^2)=2xy$, the mapping $f(z)=z^2$ is equivalent to the mapping $u=x^2-y^2,v=2xy$, so we can plot it by using the `ParametricPlot`

```
xy = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1^2 - #2^2 &, 2 #1*#2 &}, Mesh -> 8, 
   MeshShading -> {{LightRed, LightGreen}, {LightBlue, LightYellow}}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   FrameLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Blue}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];
uv = ParametricPlot[ReIm[(x + I*y)^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3^2 - #4^2 &, 2 #3*#4 &}, Mesh -> 8, 
   MeshShading -> {{LightRed, LightGreen}, {LightBlue, LightYellow}}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   FrameLabel -> {u, v}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Blue}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];
GraphicsGrid[{{xy, uv}}]
```

In the following figure, $f$ maping the level set $x^2-y^2=c$ to $u=c$ and mapping the level set $2xy=c$ to $v=c$

[image]

Another plot:

```
Block[{z = x + I y}, 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[z^2], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples.

`ContourPlot[Arg[(x + I y)^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

`ContourPlot[Abs[(x + I y)^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`

If you plot these, and also look at the documentation for `ContourPlot`, you should be on your way to making nice plots!

To answer the question about separating real and imaginary parts:  A function of one complex variable is a two dimension function of a two dimensional variable Since $z=x+iy$, the variable $z$ is equivalent to $(x,y)$, a point in two space.  A complex function is also a two dimensional function, so it is difficult to see everything all at once.

Best to plot the real and imaginary parts in two plots, or the magnitude and argument in two plots.

UPDATE:

New in *Mathematica 12.1*

```
ComplexContourPlot[AbsArg[z^2], {z, 3}, Contours -> 30]
```

[image]